# Large image shows JavaBinder(9581): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !! error

Tags: java, android, image, gallery

I have created a simple activity. The activity allows the user to choose an image from the gallery or take a picture with the camera. Mostly its working fine, but in case the user chooses an image which is a little big in size, I get the **JavaBinder(9581): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!** error in the logcat and the activity closes.

**The methods**:

```
private void choosePhoto(){

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

private void takePhoto(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    try {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            int rotationValue = ImageController.getCameraPhotoOrientation(getApplicationContext(), selectedImage, picturePath);

            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            m.postRotate(rotationValue);

            cursor.close();
            decodeImageFile(picturePath, m);
        }

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            imageUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            if (imageUri != null) {

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String cameraPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    Matrix m = new Matrix();
                    int rotationValue = ImageController.getCameraPhotoOrientation(getApplicationContext(), imageUri, cameraPath);
                    m.postRotate(rotationValue);

                    decodeImageFile(cameraPath, m);
            } else {

                    // Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Matrix m = new Matrix();
                    int rotationValue = ImageController.getCameraPhotoOrientation(getApplicationContext(), imageUri, data.getExtras().get("data").toString());
                    m.postRotate(rotationValue);
                    // Need to work out what to do about the Matrix flip in the
                    // bug
                    // for Nexus5 Cameras.

                    nexus5CameraBugFix((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"), m);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        retakePhotoDialog();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**:

```
11-26 12:31:27.441: E/JavaBinder(9581): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

**Where I am going wrong? Why am I getting the error?**

Comment: where is your logcat ?

Comment: @Hafiz.M.Usman please check edited question for logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compress your bitmap for every big bitmap you got (from gallery, from netowrk).
Here is a snippet of code that i always use when selecting image from gallery:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null,
            o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = 300;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_WIDTH
                || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_WIDTH) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
            ctx.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null,
            o2);
```

In the code above, selectedImage is the URI point to the selected image.